# Is there a way to find JavaScript memory leaks within tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, memory-leaks, jasmine

I just finished writing tests for JavaScript application and I was using Jasmine for the first time. Everything works fine, but I still need to test if application has some memory leaks within. Is it even possible to programmatically check it within my specs? Maybe there is some additional library for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no automatic way to find source of javascript memory leak. Javascript memory leaks is realy nasty thing on which you can waste a lot of time. Recently I was developing very large enterprise web solution as a single page application with almost 1mb of minimized self-written code. Suddenly we realized that our application is leaking hard. I tryied hundreds of technics to find the source of memory leak and the easiest way for me is to use `google chrome profiler`, take heap snapshot and compare different heap snapshots. Here is more information how to do it :

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Have a nice week with debugging memory leaks in your app, hope it will take less time that in my case. :)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has a non-standard extension of the window.performance API --  ([window.performance.memory](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory)), where you can measure memory usage.

In order to enable precise memory statistics, you must use this flag: `--enable-precise-memory-info`

But you also need to force GC to tell whether memory is retained after your test. Because CG doesn't happen instantly.

With Chromium browser, you can run it with a special command flag to expose a method to force GC:

```
chromium-browser --js-flags='--expose_gc'
```

This gets you access to the method `window.gc()`.